# How to swap values by changing one of them via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three fields with numbers from 1 to 3. I am trying to make it so if a person uses only the arrows there should always be one "1", one "2", and one "3". Why is it not always working and how could I make it work?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var prevNumber;
  $(".numbers").focus(function() {
    prevNumber = $(this).val();
  }).change(function() {
    curNumber = $(this).val();
    $('.numbers[value="' + curNumber + '"]:not(:focus)').first().val(prevNumber);
    prevNumber = curNumber;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q36sehw/).

Comment: "Only the arrows" as in, the browser's built-in stepper arrows for number fields?

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) rather than links to jsFiddle when possible (it's not always possible, but it is in this case). I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, these arrows. Also sorry, but I don't have enough reputation in the stackoverflow meta to test how a snippet works, so I didn't use it.

Comment: No worries. No need to test it on meta, though, you can (and should!) test it while writing your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why that approach doesn't work

The `value` *attribute* is not connected to the value of the input. I know that sound surprising. :-) The `value` attribute is the *default value* of the input. It doesn't change (unless you use `setAttribute("value", x);` or `.defaultValue = x;` to change it).

Your selector uses the *attribute*:

```
$('.numbers[value="' + curNumber + '"]')...
```

So it'll work on inputs whose value hasn't been changed by the user, but will fail once they have, selecting the wrong input.

#### How you *could* fix it

You could change the default value as well as the value by setting both `defaultValue` and `value` (being sure to update the `defaultValue` on the one that changed, too), like this (see comments):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var prevNumber;
  $(".numbers").focus(function() {
    prevNumber = $(this).val();
  }).change(function() {
    // Get the element wrapper
    var $this = $(this);
    
    // Get the current value
    var curNumber = $this.val();
    
    // Make sure the default value on this element is updated
    this.defaultValue = curNumber;
    
    // Update both the value and default value on the other
    // input that used to have this number
    $('.numbers[value="' + curNumber + '"]:not(:focus)').first().val(prevNumber).prop("defaultValue", prevNumber);
    prevNumber = curNumber;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### What I'd do instead *(maybe -- your approach is growing on me)*

I think I'd approach it without trying to remember state, e.g., just in the `change`: Get the number of the one that changed, then assign any other numbers to its siblings. See the comments:

```js
var numbers = $(".numbers").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".numbers").change(function() {
    // Get a wrapper for this input
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get this number
    var thisNumber = $this.val();
    // Get the unused numbers
    var unused = numbers.filter(function(num) { return num != thisNumber; });
    // Assign them to the siblings, in order
    $this.siblings().val(function(index) {
      return unused[index];
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I kept that general, rather than assuming the values would only be 1, 2, and 3 (and rather than assuming there'd only be three numbers).

Comment: @JuanMendes: I've updated to explain why the OP's current approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that the "value" attribute contains the **initial** value for the input. When you use the following selector:

```
$('.numbers[value="' + curNumber + '"]:not(:focus)')
```

you are selecting the element that **initially** had the given value, and not has this value now.
Try this selector instead, and all will work fine:

```
$('.numbers:not(:focus)').filter(function(index, element){ 
    return $(element).val() == curNumber; 
  })
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qscjc1xr/). ;)

Comment: P.S. See value attribute documentation here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value

Comment: I  tried using `$.attr('value', curNumber)` to get around the problem that `.value` doesn't update the attribute, but it still didn't work https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/f49yn7uo/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose you a more elaborate solution that might help you as your application grows: you should store the JS value apart from the `<input />` controlling it (this way, adding multiple `<input>`s or modifying the value from your code becomes easier. The most important thing is that you should have a **single trusted data storage independent from the DOM that is always in a valid state** (in this case: without duplicates).

Given your problem (the values should be unique and only swaps should be possible), it's easier to handle it as a pure JS problem (and do not try to do everything in jQuery - though I agree it's a great lib, it's not necessarily the best tool for everything).

Here is my commented solution:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // This array the current values of the inputs
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

  // numbers should not be modified directly but trough
  // setNumber: this function ensures that numbers is ALWAYS
  // a swap of the original value ([1, 2, 3]).
  // When a value is set, this function returns the previous
  // index of the value
  function setNumber(index, newVal) {
    // find other index
    var prevIndex = numbers.indexOf(newVal);
    if (prevIndex < 0) {
      alert('Invalid value, please enter 1, 2 or 3');
    }
    // swap
    numbers[prevIndex] = numbers[index];
    numbers[index] = newVal;
    return prevIndex;
  }

  // This function updates the inputs to ensure
  // that their displayed value match the one stored in numbers
  function updateNumbersView() {
    $(".numbers").each(function(idx, elem) {
      elem = $(elem);
      if (parseInt(elem.val(), 10) !== numbers[idx]) {
        elem.val(numbers[idx]);
      }
    });
  }

  $(".numbers").change(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var curNumber = parseInt(self.val(), 10);
    var curIndex = $(".numbers").index(self);
    if (curNumber === numbers[curIndex]) {
      return false; // no change
    }
    
    // update model:
    var changedIndex = setNumber(curIndex, curNumber);
    
    // updateView:
    $('.numbers').eq(changedIndex).val(numbers[changedIndex]);
    
    // or to be more generic (ie. multiple inputs for the same value):
    // updateNumbersView();
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by adding another property to each node.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $numbers = $('.numbers'),
        off = false;
    $numbers.each(function () {
        this.prev = this.value;
    });
    $numbers.change(function () {
        var source = this;
        if (off) return; // this algorithm is already running
        off = true;
        $numbers.each(function () {
            if (this !== source && this.value === source.value) { // if conflict
                this.prev = this.value = source.prev; // swap with old value
            }
        });
        this.prev = this.value; // update for next time
        off = false; // re-enable
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="3" step="1" class="numbers" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```